# Instagram Content Publishing - Unsupported post request. Object with ID ' does not exist

Tags: facebook-graph-api, django-allauth, instagram-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to post an image to an Instagram account connected to my facebook account. I obtained a token using Django All auth's Facebook provider.

On checking the permissions associated with the token using [Access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?)

I got the following perissions for my token -

**Scopes:   email, pages_show_list, instagram_basic, instagram_content_publish, public_profile**
Granular Scopes:
pages_show_list           -  Applies to all objects
instagram_basic           -  Applies to all objects
instagram_content_publish -  Applies to all objects

I tried the following steps but I am not able to create an Image container to post on Instagram.

1. I called the **accounts** endpoint to get all the accounts associated with the token.

   curl -i -X GET 
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/accounts?access_token=XYZ"
2. Use the page id from above response to get the Instagram business account id

   curl -i -X GET 
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/<IG_USER_ID>?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token=XYZ"
3. Tried to create an Image container but getting an error

   curl -i -X POST 
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/<IG_USER_ID>/media?image_url=https://images.pexels.com/photos/15925339/pexels-photo-15925339/free-photo-of-lonely-swan.jpeg&caption=#BronzFonz&access_token=XYZ"

Error -

> {
> "error": {
> "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '17841......' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
> permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
> API documentation at
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
> "type": "GraphMethodException",
> "code": 100,
> "error_subcode": 33,
> "fbtrace_id": "AZEDqeP95PNePeLRooUC41e"
> } }

I am following the documentation here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/ Not sure where I am making a mistake.

My app is currently in dev mode and my requested permissions haven't been reviewed. I'll send for approval once my app is ready.

Comment: Error code 100 means you are passing Invalid parameter. Are you sure if you are getting correct IG_USER_ID. Bdw, you have mistyped IG_USER_ID in step2 instead it should be page-id in url.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, yea I meant the page id. I have posted an answer below. I had a missing permission.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing a few permissions. The facebook documentation present [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/)

doesn't mention the "pages_manage_posts" permission. So I was facing the issue because of the same. Here's the complete list of permissions I am using and I am able to create the IG image container now.

> "email",
> "pages_show_list",
> "instagram_basic",
> "instagram_manage_comments",
> "instagram_content_publish",
> "pages_read_engagement",
> "pages_manage_metadata",
> "pages_manage_posts",
> "public_profile",